# Does graphics card affect the server performance

Tags: performance, graphics-processing-unit

I was wondering does graphics card actually improve the performance of the server or a dedicated cpu is already enough to do the job. If graphic cards capacity is needed how many does it required?

If for Nas Or for Webhosting Or dedicated software purpose

Answer (score 2):

For the vast majority of server workloads, no - a graphics card is not used. This is true for web servers and NAS's.

There are a few exceptions - some specific algorythythms can be massively sped up with GPUs and there are servers designed specifically for these workloads. These include some types of coin mining, password cracking, Artificial intelligence, some kinds of graphics rendering. (google CUDA for a language used to work with GPUs). The types of load tend to be simpler sets of instructions which can be massively paralleled.

Comment: For a NAS workload even the CPU is typically not that important - with the RAID controller and disks being the focus - especially for RAID6 (although this can be done in software as well)